# How to refresh your JTextPane from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I know this question has been asked several times. I am trying to refresh my JTextPane from another class, and when I do it from my main class it works, but any other classes it doesnt. I heard you need to use threads to do it, but I have yet to actually see someone implement it. I have provided my code below as simply as possible. There are 3 classes. Thanks!

Here is the output of what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5CYV.jpg

```
______________________________________________________
public class frame extends JPanel implements Runnable {

public TextBox textbox = new TextBox();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new TextBox());

    public void run(){

    }
    public frame(){     

        t1.start();
        textField();

    }
public void textField(){
    add(textbox.sp);          
}

}

___________________________________________________

//bunch of imports

public class TextBox implements Runnable {

        JTextPane field = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(field);
        String name ="This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message";
        public void run(){    

        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
                   System.out.println("hello thread");                                                             
            }catch(Exception e){}
         }            

    public TextBox(){
        field.setText("Welcome to Stack Overflow!!\n");  
        Message();
        }
    public void Message(){
                Style style = field.addStyle("I'm a Style", null);
                            StyledDocument doc = field.getStyledDocument();
                            StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.BLACK);
                            field.setCaretPosition(field.getText().length());                                    
                            try { doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), GetText(),style); }
                                    catch (BadLocationException e){} 
   Color color=new Color(255,255,255); 
   field.setBackground(color);  
   sp.setBounds(100, 335, 350, 100);
   field.setEditable(false);
   sp.setAutoscrolls(true);
    }
    public String GetText ( )
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void SetText (String PassedText)
    {
        name = PassedText;           
    }
}
```

---

//Ive created a new class to demonstrate what I am trying to do when I change the doc.

---

```
public class ChangePane {
     public TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    ChangePane(){

    Style style = textbox.field.addStyle("I'm a Style", null);

    StyledDocument doc = textbox.field.getStyledDocument();

    try {doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "TESTING     ADDITION",style);}catch(BadLocationException e){}

    textbox.Message();
    }

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use a JTextPane and not the simpler JTextArea?

Comment: You need to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. ..

Comment: .. 4) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

> I am trying to refresh my JTextPane from another class,

As for updating a field in another class, you should give the class that holds the field a public method that other classes can call that changes the state of that field. For instance if you want to allow another class to change the text in a `JTextField`, then give your class a method like:

```
public void setMyTextFieldText(String text) {
    myTextField.setText(text);

    // or if a JTextPane by inserting text into its Document here
}
```

This has nothing to do with Swing or GUI's and all to do with basic Java and object oriented coding. For a JTextPane you'd need to do more then just setText, I believe, but I don't use them much.

> and when I do it from my main class it works, but any other classes it doesnt. I heard you need to use threads to do it, but I have yet to actually see someone implement it. I have provided my code below as simply as possible.

The threading issue comes in if you are making changes to your Swing GUI off of the EDT (event dispatch thread) which is the main Swing thread. If this occurs, then yes you should queue your Swing calls onto the Swing event thread by putting it into a Runnable and putting on the Swing event queue:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // your swing calls go here
  }
});
```

---

**Edit 1**
Note, this method of yours does nothing of use:

```
// you should rename this setText(String passedText)
public void SetText (String PassedText)
{
    name = PassedText;           
    // you need to change your JTextPane's Document in here *****
}
```

All it does is change the text referred to by the name String field, but that won't change any displayed text. You will have to change the JTextPane text by calling JTextPane methods, by inserting text into the JTextPane's Document.

---

**Edit 2**
Please learn about and use Java naming conventions so as not to confuse folks who might want to understand your code and help you. Class names should begin with an upper-case letter and variable and field names with a lower-case letter. Your naming appears to be backwards.

---

**Edit 3**
You know that you have two completely independent TextBox objects here:

```
public TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
Thread t1 = new Thread(new TextBox());
```

Changing the state of one will have no effect on the other.

Also, why are you having your component classes implement Runnable and then putting them in Threads. That makes little sense. To understand Swing threading, please read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

---

**Edit 4**
An example of an [sscce](http://sscce.org):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextBoxTest {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private MyTextBox myTextBox = new MyTextBox();
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 30);

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public TextBoxTest() {
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
      scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("JTextArea"),
            scrollPane.getBorder()));

      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
      centerPanel.add(myTextBox.getMainComponent());
      centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Submit Text") {
         {
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
         }

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
               myTextBox.setText(textArea.getText());
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }));
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Append Text") {
         {
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_A);
         }

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
               myTextBox.appendText(textArea.getText() + "\n");
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }));      
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Append Red Text") {
         {
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_R);
         }

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
               myTextBox.appendTextInRed(textArea.getText() + "\n");
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }));

      mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   public JComponent getMainComponent() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TextBoxTest textBoxTester = new TextBoxTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextBoxTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(textBoxTester.getMainComponent());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyTextBox {
   private JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
   private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
   private String name = "This is your message!! Message  Message "
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n"
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n"
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n"
         + "This is your message!! Message  Message "
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n"
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n";
   private StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

   public MyTextBox() {
      addStylesToDocument(doc);
      textPane.setEditable(false);
      textPane.setFocusable(false);
      try {
         doc.insertString(0, name, doc.getStyle("regular"));
      } catch (BadLocationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("JTextPane"),
            scrollPane.getBorder()));
   }

   private void addStylesToDocument(StyledDocument doc2) {
      Style def = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(
            StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);

      Style regular = doc.addStyle("regular", def);
      StyleConstants.setFontFamily(def, "SansSerif");
      StyleConstants.setFontSize(regular, 16);

      Style s = doc.addStyle("red", regular);
      StyleConstants.setForeground(s, Color.red);

   }

   public JScrollPane getMainComponent() {
      return scrollPane;
   }

   public void setText(String text) throws BadLocationException {
      doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());
      doc.insertString(0, text, doc.getStyle("regular"));
   }

   public void appendText(String text) throws BadLocationException {
      doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, doc.getStyle("regular"));
   }

   public void appendTextInRed(String text) throws BadLocationException {
      doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, doc.getStyle("red"));
   }

}
```

---

**Edit 5**
To send from another thread, as I have noted elsewhere simply wrap the code into a Runnable and queue it onto the EDT via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(myRunnable)`.

For instance, I can give the MyTextBox class a method that does all this, and any outside class can call it:

```
public void appendTextOffEdt(final String text) {
  // first make sure that we're in fact off of the EDT
  if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
     try {
        appendTextInRedBold(text);
     } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  } else {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           try {
              appendTextInRedBold(text);
           } catch (BadLocationException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
     });
  }
}
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextBoxTest {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private MyTextBox myTextBox = new MyTextBox();
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 30);
   private SendTextOffEdt sendTextOffEdt = new SendTextOffEdt(myTextBox);

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public TextBoxTest() {
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
      scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("JTextArea"),
            scrollPane.getBorder()));

      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
      centerPanel.add(myTextBox.getMainComponent());
      centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

      new Thread(sendTextOffEdt).start();

      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Append Text") {
         {
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_A);
         }

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
               myTextBox.appendText(textArea.getText() + "\n");
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }));
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Append Blue Text") {
         {
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_B);
         }

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
               myTextBox.appendTextInBlue(textArea.getText() + "\n");
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }));
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Exit") {
         {
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_X);
         }

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
            win.dispose();
         }
      }));

      mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   public JComponent getMainComponent() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TextBoxTest textBoxTester = new TextBoxTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextBoxTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(textBoxTester.getMainComponent());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SendTextOffEdt implements Runnable {
   private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 3000;
   private static final String TEXT = "Sent off of EDT\n";
   private MyTextBox myTextBox;

   public SendTextOffEdt(MyTextBox myTextBox) {
      this.myTextBox = myTextBox;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      while (true) {
         myTextBox.appendTextOffEdt(TEXT);
         try {
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         }
      }
   }
}

class MyTextBox {
   public static final String REGULAR = "regular";
   public static final String BLUE = "blue";
   public static final String RED_BOLD = "red bold";
   private JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
   private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
   private String name = "This is your message!! Message  Message "
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n"
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n"
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n"
         + "This is your message!! Message  Message "
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n"
         + "This is your message!!\n\n Message \n\n Message \n\n";
   private StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

   public MyTextBox() {
      addStylesToDocument(doc);
      textPane.setEditable(false);
      textPane.setFocusable(false);
      try {
         doc.insertString(0, name, doc.getStyle("regular"));
      } catch (BadLocationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("JTextPane"),
            scrollPane.getBorder()));
   }

   private void addStylesToDocument(StyledDocument doc2) {
      Style def = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(
            StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);

      Style regular = doc.addStyle(REGULAR, def);
      StyleConstants.setFontFamily(def, "SansSerif");
      StyleConstants.setFontSize(regular, 16);

      Style s = doc.addStyle(BLUE, regular);
      StyleConstants.setForeground(s, Color.blue);

      s = doc.addStyle(RED_BOLD, regular);
      StyleConstants.setBold(s, true);
      StyleConstants.setForeground(s, Color.red);

   }

   public JScrollPane getMainComponent() {
      return scrollPane;
   }

   public void setText(String text) throws BadLocationException {
      doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());
      doc.insertString(0, text, doc.getStyle(REGULAR));
   }

   public void appendText(String text) throws BadLocationException {
      doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, doc.getStyle(REGULAR));
   }

   public void appendTextInBlue(String text) throws BadLocationException {
      doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, doc.getStyle(BLUE));
   }

   public void appendTextInRedBold(String text) throws BadLocationException {
      doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, doc.getStyle(RED_BOLD));
   }

   public void appendTextOffEdt(final String text) {
      // first make sure that we're in fact off of the EDT
      if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
         try {
            appendTextInRedBold(text);
         } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      } else {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               try {
                  appendTextInRedBold(text);
               } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

---

As for tutorials:

- [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)
- [Event Dispatch Thread Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Java Tutorials Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)

Comment: There is a `JTextPane` declaration in the `TextBox` class, it is the first line.

Comment: @JoshM: didn't see that, but now do. Updated answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "The threading issue comes in if you are making changes to your Swing GUI off of the EDT (event dispatch thread) which is the main Swing thread. If this occurs, then yes you should queue your Swing calls onto the Swing event thread by putting it into a Runnable and putting on the Swing event queue." Yes this is what people have been doing but I would like to see it implemented. I tried it on my actual program and it didnt work. So i thought this simple example might help show where someone would put that code

Comment: @CameronRoberson: your problem is not a threading problem, so put that to the side. Your problem is that you're changing the state of a String variable, `name`, but not changing the JTextPane's Document in any significant way.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for the help. So you say I should change my JTextPane document. Ive tried:
     Style style = textbox.field.addStyle("I'm a Style", null);
     StyledDocument doc = textbox.field.getStyledDocument();
     try {doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "TESTING      ADDITION",style);}catch(BadLocationException e){}

Comment: @CameronRoberson: "I've tried" tells us little that we can use to help. If you've tried something new, please add the new code and text explaining what happens or doesn't happen, what errors occur. Add it to the bottom of your original question and then notify me and others interested in helping you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have added the code I have been trying. When you said I need to edit the doc, this is the only way I know how to edit it. But it still doesnt appear when i run the program. Thanks for your diligence!

Comment: @CameronRoberson: Sorry but your code makes no sense. Please create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org), something that we can test and run ourselves. Have you gone through the Swing tutorials on use of JTextPane? They have a sample program that you will want to review and modify.

Comment: @CameronRoberson: for example, please see my [sscce](http://sscce.org) posted as **edit 4**.

Comment: @HovercraftFUllofEels Hi again, I appreciate the work you are doing for helping me with my problem. But, I am not trying to update my JTextPane with action events. At least, this is what I saw on the short example. I am trying to get the JTextPane to change when a method is called in another class. I am trying to avoid action events. Maybe JTextPane wasnt the best choice for what I want to do...Do you know how I could change the text by calling a method? Also where is this swing tutorial you mentioned? Thanks Again,

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hey, I tried your example and am in the process of understanding how it works. For the mean time I am working around it in my program. I really appreciate your help, and im confident it will lead to my solution in the future :) Thanks!! If you ever want to chat privately about java and programs etc. let me know if your not to busy.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added the timed addition of text to the textbox to my program and it works great! Thanks a lot. I have another question for you now. How would I notify this thread from another class to only print into the textbox when I wanted it to? Thanks,

Comment: @CameronRoberson: that sounds like it should be part of a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have created a new post based on the code you gave me. You can find it here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239312/how-to-update-a-thread-from-another-class
Thanks for all your help
~Cam